# "Range Error: Maximum call stack size limit exceeded" on using greptcha.reset() method

Tags: validation, recaptcha, captcha, grecaptcha, anti-bot

I am using google recaptcha V2, for captcha verification. Recently, I am facing issue while resetting the captcha using `grecaptcha.reset()` method.

Refer error screenshot below:

[image]

Have checked the same scenario in the google recaptcha demo website and the same issue exists.

Can any one help with this? Is there any workaround. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've started seeing these errors in a production application this week and haven't yet been able to diagnose it either. It's unclear why are usage is causing what appears to be an infinite loop inside Google's Recaptcha code.

Comment: This has also happened to me this week, perhaps this has been caused by a change on google's end?

Comment: I guess we have solved this issue. For us the scenario was using multiple captchas in a single page. The issue occurs when we load multiple api.js file (part of google recaptcha) in the same html page. Now when there are multiple js files loaded, the captcha loaded by the greptcha.reset function gets into infinite loop when checked.
As a fix:
1. Load only one recatpcha api.JS file in the HTML body.  

Make sure there is only one api.js is loaded in the page.

Comment: Same situation here. I accidentally loaded reCaptcha's api.js twice on the same page, which caused the issue.